# UITableView in xCode 7.3 without UITableViewController

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitableview, xcode7.3

I'm trying to load an `UITableView` from a xib file. I created an `UIView` object which I use in order to load the xib file. Here I added an `UITableView` but with the last update of Xcode, I can't figure out how to include a prototype cell inside this table view.

Here there is my code of the `UIView` which loads the xib file:

```
class TopChartView: UIView, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var tableViewChart: UITableView!

    var view : UIView!    

    var prova = [String]()


    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)


        prova.append("hi")
        prova.append("bye")

        self.tableViewChart = UITableView()

        self.tableViewChart.delegate = self
        self.tableViewChart.dataSource = self

        self.tableViewChart.registerClass(TopChartTVCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "TopChart_IDcell")

        //carico il file xib
        xibSetup()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }


    func xibSetup() {

        Global.log.action()

        view = loadViewFromNib()
        // Make the view stretch with containing view
        view.autoresizingMask = [UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth, UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleHeight]
        self.addSubview(view)

        Global.log.action(methodEnded: true)
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        Global.log.action()

        let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
        view.frame.size.width = screenSize.width
        view.frame.size.height = screenSize.height
        view.frame.origin.x = 0
        view.frame.origin.y = 0

        Global.log.action(methodEnded: true)
    }

    func loadViewFromNib() -> UIView {

        Global.log.action()

        let bundle = NSBundle(forClass: self.dynamicType)
        let nib = UINib(nibName: Constants.topChartVC.xibFileName, bundle: bundle)
        let view = nib.instantiateWithOwner(self, options: nil)[0] as! UIView

        Global.log.action(methodEnded: true)
        return view
    }



    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return self.prova.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("TopChart_IDcell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TopChartTVCell

        let elem = self.prova[indexPath.row]

        cell.label.text = elem
        return cell
    }
}
```

And here there is my simple xib which is the problem because I'm not able to add an `UITableViewCell` inside the `UITableView`:

[image]

Comment: you don't need to initialise it again `self.tableViewChart = UITableView()` if the tableview is linked to the view via `@IBOutlet`. And is `TopChartTVCell.self` the cell you want to use?

Comment: Yes it is! But how can I insert it "inside" the table view in the xib file? thanks

Comment: Anyway I need to initialize it because the `@IBOutlet` references to the file's owner, if I don't initialize it I get an error..

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't know how you can insert a cell inside the table view in a xib file, what I normally do is creating another xib file for the cell itself....However, if you initialised it like this `self.tableViewChart = UITableView()`, you'll lose everything that's inside the xib file. If you really really have to initialise the tableview itself from code, then you should use `NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed` method.

Comment: You are right, I just understood that is not possible to use a prototype cell inside a xib file! I did what you said (a different xib for the cell) and now it works!! Thanks you!